# How to set element value with namespace in linq?

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq-to-xml, xnamespace

I am developing silverlight web part for sharepoint 2010. I have an xml file in my application as follows

```
<sst xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" count="67" uniqueCount="39">
  <si>
    <t>INVOICE</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>INVOICE #</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Bill To:</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    < t>DESCRIPTION</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>AMOUNT</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>TOTAL</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>FOR:</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Positive Behavior Support Corp</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>8108 SE Coconut St.</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Hobe Sound, FL 33455</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>772-349-6317 Phone  772-675-9100 Fax</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>EIN 20-5268843</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Provider 693068996</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Rate</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Units</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>DATE</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Michael Nolan Ph.D. BCBA</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>____________________________________________</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>BCBA                          Date</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>CLIENT:</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Date:</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Behavior Assistant- L. Bresson</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Email:</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>1 Unit = 1 hour</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>TOTALS</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>cvt1970@juno.com</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Attn: Cecilia</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Behavior Assistant- B. Bresson</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Behaviror Ass't -N Giarratano</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Signature of Representatives Approval           Date</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <r>
      <t xml:space="preserve">Behavior Asst- </t>
    </r>
    <r>
      <rPr>
        <sz val="9" />
        <rFont val="Arial" />
        <family val="2" />
      </rPr>
      <t>N Giarratano-</t>
    </r>
    <r>
      <rPr>
        <sz val="10" />
        <rFont val="Arial" />
        <family val="2" />
      </rPr>
      <t>08</t>
    </r>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Behavior Asst- B. Bresson-08</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>Behavior Asst- L. Bresson-08</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>&lt;@Invoice&gt;</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>&lt;@For&gt;</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>&lt;@Client&gt;</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>&lt;@Caregiver&gt;</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>&lt;@Email,@Address,@City,@State,@Zip&gt;</t>
  </si>
  <si>
    <t>&lt;@Date&gt;</t>
  </si>
</sst>
```

I am successfully loading this xml file. Now I am acessing all the element with name "t" from xml file as follows.

```
XNamespace ns = xmlDoc.Root.Name.Namespace;
            var eles = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants(ns + "si")
                       select c.Element(ns + "t");
```

It is also working fine.
But when I use the following query it gives me error

```
eles.Elements(ns + "t").Where(x => x.Element(ns + "t").Value == "&lt;@Date&gt;").SingleOrDefault().SetElementValue(ns + "t","hi");
```

It gives me error as object reference is not set to instance of object. How I can replace the "<@Date> with "hi" in the existing xml. Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Comment: I AM getting null in the result view at position [30]. Can it be the reason for not working ? If it is the reason then how should I write the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `eles` variable is already returning the `<t>`. None of the `<t>` have a child that is `<t>`, so it makes sense that `x.Element(ns + "t")` doesn't return anything (thus `null`, thus `.Value` is an error). Actually, I'm a bit confused, because `eles.Elements(ns + "t")` should have been an empty sequence.

Also, the value in C# terms is `<@Date>`; the `&gt;` / `&lt;` only applies to xml.

Also, the query is being impacted by the one `<si>` that doesn't have a `<t>`; a better variant would be:

```
var eles = xmlDoc.Descendants(ns + "si").Elements(ns + "t");
```

(which handles 0, 1, or many `<t>` per `<si>`)

Then after that, you mean:

```
eles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value == "<@Date>").Value = "hi";
```

Comment: It is not working. I am getting the null value in x in the query eles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value == "<@Date>").Value = "hi"; It is still giving error 'object reference is not set to an instance of object.I am getting null value in the result set of 'eles' at position [30]. Can it be the reason for not working ? If it is the reason then how should I write the query

Comment: [Duplicate of comment below] Have you seen my comment about debugging? Set a breakpoint and inspect the list of elements returned by your first query. Look for the one with the Value you require. Do a bit of problem solving for yourself!

Comment: @ShaileshJaiswal did you see the revised `eles` query I wrote? The issue is that, as I wrote, one of your `<si>` lacks a `<t>`, which means `c.Element(ns + "t")` returns `null` for that record. I removed that issue above, with a different `eles` query.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query returns elements with the name 't', your second query then looks for children of these elements, also with the name 't'. This does not match the structure of your document, Your second query should be:

```
var matchingElement = eles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value == "&lt;@Date&gt;");
```

You can then perform your replacement.

I would recommend using your debugger when developing code. If you breakpoint then inspect the `eles` variable you can actually see what is returned by your first query.

Comment: It is not working. I am getting the null value in x in the query var matchingElement = eles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value == "&lt;@Date&gt;"); It is still giving error 'object reference is not set to an instance of object.I am getting null value in the result set of 'eles' at position [30]. Can it be the reason for not working ? If it is the reason then how should I write the query

Comment: Have you seen my comment about debugging? Set a breakpoint and inspect the list of elements returned by your first query. Look for the one with the Value you require. Do a bit of problem solving for yourself!

Comment: I have set the breakpoint and seen the result of 'eles'. In that there is null value at position [30]. There is system.xml.linq.XElemnet[0] is the 'Empty sequence' and at position [38] there is a value I require.

Comment: Note that the value is not `&lt;@Date&gt;` - it is `<@Date>`.

Comment: @ShaileshJaiswal I already explained the whole issue with that `null`, and posted the fix to your broken `eles` query...